# calendar: March 31st in 2024 not a holiday, even when marked ("Checking holidays...done")

Tags: calendar

I found this issue in Emacs of SLES 12 SP5 (`emacs-x11-24.3-25.12.1.x86_64`):

I opened the calendar (`M-x` calendar), marked the holidays (<kbd>x</kbd>), then moved to the holidays, pressing <kbd>h</kbd> to find out which holiday it is.
That worked fine for the first holidays inspected, but it fails for March 31st 2024 which is supposed to be Easter Sunday.

Instead of displaying the holiday in the status line, all I get is:

> Checking holidays...done

March 29th and April 1st work as expected.

Listing all holidays I get:

```text
...
Friday, March 29, 2024: Good Friday
Sunday, March 31, 2024: Daylight Saving Time Begins 2:00am (CET)
Sunday, March 31, 2024: Easter Sunday
Monday, April 1, 2024: April Fools' Day
...
```

What might be the issue?

[image: Partial screenshot showing Emacs calendar in PuTTY window]

Comment: In Emacs 29.1 typing `h` on that date tells me `Sunday, March 31, 2024:  Easter Sunday` -- so somewhere between your version 24.3 (release date 2013-03-10) and the current stable release 29.1 this issue was resolved.

Comment: I get the desired behaviour in Emacs 25.3 as well (which is the oldest version I currently have available).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no problem: the OP failed to notice that holiday was indeed marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid:
The "frame" was quite tall, and the two "holidays" were written on top of the tall frame (in another "window") while I stared at the status line at the bottom.
Like this:

[image: Screenshot showing two Emacs calendar windows in a tall frame]

Comment: Should I delete the question, or should I keep it for "other blind people"?

Comment: You may `close` the question.

Comment: I cannot "Close"; I can only "Delete", but that gives a warning: "*We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge. *".

Comment: Mark your own answer as the solution then, so that it does not get periodically bumped to the top of the list by the community bot.

Comment: Mark it accepted or close it (disregard the warning). But do *not* leave it hanging as it is.